# Ошибка при создании строки

Tags: c++, строки

вот код:

```
int x,y;
const int n;
cin>>x,y,n;
string arr[n];
arr[0] = "(" + x + "," + y + ")"; //вот тут ошибка invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'|
```

Раньше работал с пхп, джаваскриптом, тут - ничего не понимаю, почему ошибка и  как сложить строки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотя бы так:

```
int x,y;
int n;
cin>>x>>y>>n;
string *arr = new string[n];
arr[0] = "(" + to_string(x) + "," + to_string(y) + ")";
```

Вот еще вариант:

```
int x,y;
int n;
cin>>x>>y>>n;
string *arr = new string[n];
ostringstream os;
os << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
arr[0] = os.str();
```

Comment: Только хотел так же написать :)

Comment: ошибка 'to_string' was not declared in this scope :/ уже искал ее в интернете, не понимаю в чем дело

Comment: Может, какой совсем уж древний компилятор?... Вы чем пользуетесь?